# Azure pipeline jobs queue by agent

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Anyone can please let me how to do that - "I need to queue the whole Run. Only have one Run at a time" Is there any way to restrict azure agent to run all jobs from pipeline and the run jobs from another pipeline

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show what you have tried so far. There is a better chance that you will get a high quality answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically agent queue the jobs and run one by one.By default there are two type of Agent jobs in Devops.

1. Microsoft-hosted
2. Self-hosted

If you go to Parallel under Pipelines in Organisation settings you can see how many parallel jobs able to run with your subscription and you cant change it.
[image]

Comment: Thanks dude but actually I want to execute all jobs coded in one pipeline and then attempt to execute other jobs from other pipeline. As example, I have written a multiple azure pipeline in a way where each pipeline consist two jobs and I am running all pipeline in one self hosted agent but while executing all pipelines on same agent then multiple jobs from same pipeline are not queued and not executed one after

Comment: I m not clear about multiple jobs from same pipeline. i guess you saying about agent job in pipeline. but naturally these jobs ruining one after the other?

Comment: Yes, I meant to say agent jobs in pipeline. As in my case I have two jobs i.e. P1job1 and P1job2 in pipeline i.e. P1 and there are other jobs i.e. P2job3 and P2job4 in pipeline i.e. P2, so now I am trying to run these pipelines against one same self hosted agent.

So when those pipelines were trigger then P1job1 from P1 pipeline has started running and P2job3 from P2 pipeline would be the next queue, so is there any way to queue the P1job2 from P1 pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the pipeline jobs on a specific agent, we can configure demand to specify the agent job.
Steps:

1. Open org settings->agent pools->select agent-> open the tab Capabilities->add Capabilities.
2. Open pipeline->click agent job and enter new demands.
3. Then run the pipeline.

It will make the current jobs run on an agent that meets the capability based on your defined demand. Please refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more details.

I hope it can help you.

Update1

**Update1**

As a workaround, we can [configure pipeline trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to trigger one pipeline after another pipeline complete. The pipeline will not be queued until the build is complete.

Sample:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: securitylib   # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: security-lib-ci # Name of the triggering pipeline
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - releases/*
      - master
```

Comment: Thanks Vito but actually I want to execute all jobs coded in one pipeline and then attempt to execute other jobs from other pipeline. As example, I have written a multiple azure pipeline in a way where each pipeline consist two jobs and I am running all pipeline in one self hosted agent but while executing all pipelines on same agent then multiple jobs from same pipeline are not queued and not executed one after

Comment: Hi Ashish,
I have updated the answer, please check it.

Comment: Hey Vito, is there any other way to do instead of specifying pipeline name in other pipeline as in my case those pipelines are independent but I want to finish jobs of a pipeline to finish all then go to other jobs of pipeline?

Comment: In the default setting, we can only run one pipeline at a time, If we run the second pipeline, it will queue until the first pipeline is completed. We cannot change it, if you need this feature, we recommend that you submit a [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). I hope it can help you.